# in flutter row doesn't display anything

Tags: android-studio, flutter, row

[error][1]Good day, 

I am a beginner in Flutter 
I face a problem 
*Row* doesn't display anything 
and when I replace *Row* with *Column*, everything goes well


Thank you for your help

```
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Element 1",
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 70,
                fontFamily: "DancingScript",
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
              )
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtrEC.png
```

Comment: wrap text with expanded widget

Comment: I've copied your code to a clean project and it works: https://i.imgur.com/eYWUIiD.png Your issue is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @JoãoSoares , thanks . but Excuse me, which tools do you use ? I use android studio when I faced this problem

Comment: I am also using Android studio and the Android emulator that comes with it.

Comment: I have tested it on android studio and vscode and in both the row is displayed maybe you are having some different issue.